# Fail to install R package from source - special character in path

Tags: r, package

when I try to install a package from source (e.g. github), I get an error

```
* installing *source* package 'burglr' ...
** using staged installation
Error in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") : 
  (converti depuis l'avis) impossible d'ouvrir le fichier 
'C:/Users/Valirie/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/00LOCK- 
burglr/00new/burglr/DESCRIPTION' : No such file or directory
ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package 'burglr'
* removing 'C:/Users/Valérie/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/burglr'
```

I guess that this is due to the special character in name "Valérie" that is read as "Valirie" during the process. Is there any possibility to solve this issue?

Comment: Change your locale settings temporarily to French?

Comment: can you  test your hypothesis by using the `lib` argument to install to a different location without special characters and confirm that it works?

Comment: see also https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/221532947-Problem-with-special-characters-in-path and https://gist.github.com/kevinushey/32ea69f6c64a4171d987405712c6a387 ...

Comment: I tried to change the lib argument, but now I always get this message:
Error: Failed to install 'burglr' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) 'lib = "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.1/library"' is not writable